# MVC 3 TextBoxes for 1 Model Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On a form, I would like to use 3 text boxes to represent one Model property (a phone number). The phone number will be stored as a string like this - "614-555-4321". I want 3 text boxes to hold each of the three parts of the phone number that someone is entering. What is the easiest/best way to accomplish this?

Right now I have - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactInfo.Phone)`

How can I split it into 3 text boxes, then map it back to the `ContactInfo.Phone` property with "-" between the three parts of the phone number when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use three input properties in the view-model, and combine to get the phone number:

```
public string Area { get; set; }
public string Prefix { get; set; }
public string Suffix { get; set; }

public string Phone 
{
    get { return string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", Area, Prefix, Suffix); }
}
```

And:

```
(@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Area)) @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Prefix)-@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Suffix)
```